# Purpose of web app input validation for security reasons

Tags: validation, security, xss, sql-injection, code-injection

I often encounter advice for protecting a web application against a number of vulnerabilities, like SQL injection and other types of injection, by doing input validation.
It's sometimes even said to be the single most important technique.

Personally, I feel that input validation for security reasons is never necessary and better replaced with

- if possible, not mixing user input with a programming language at all (e.g. using parameterized SQL statements instead of concatenating input in the query strings)
- escaping user input before mixing it with a programming or markup language (e.g. html escaping, javascript escaping, ...)

Of course for a good UX it's best to catch input that would generate errors on the backand early in the GUI, but that's another matter.

Am I missing something or is the only purpose to try to make up for mistakes against the above two rules?

Comment: Actually this question probably belongs on https://security.stackexchange.com -> is there a way to move it?

Comment: Maybe ask for it to be migrated on Meta or in chat since there's no option for Security SE in the flag list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are generally correct.

A piece of data is only dangerous when "used". And it is only dangerous if it has special meaning in the context it is used.

For example, `<script>` is only dangerous if used in output to an HTML page.

`Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` is only dangerous [when used in a database query](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Generally, you want to make this data "safe" as late as possible. Such as HTML encoding when output as HTML to an HTML page, and parameterised when inserting into a database. The big advantage of this is that when the data is later retrieved from these locations, it will be returned in its original, unsanitized format.

So if you have the value `A&B O'Leary` in an input field, it would be encoded like so:

```
<input type="hidden" value="A&amp; O&#x27;Leary" />
```

and if this is submitted to your application, your programming framework will automatically decode it for you back to `A&B O'Leary`. Same with your DB:

```
string name = "A&B O'Leary";
string sql = "INSERT INTO Customers (Name) VALUES (@Name)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", name];
```

Simples.

Additionally if you then need to give the user any output in plain text, you should retrieve it from your DB and spit it out. Or in JavaScript - [you just JavaScript entity encode](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values) (although best avoided for complexity reasons - I find it easier to secure if I only output to HTML then read the values from the DOM).

If you'd HTML encoded it early, then to output to JavaScript/JSON you'd first have to convert it back then hex entity encode it. It will get messy and some developers will forget they have to decode first and you will have &amps everywhere.

You *can* use validation as an additional defence, but it should not be the first port of call. For example, if you are validating a UK postcode you would want to whitelist the alphanumeric characters in upper and lower cases. Any other characters would be rejected or removed by your application. This can reduce the chances of SQLi or XSS occurring on your application, but this method falls down where you need inputs to include characters that have special meaning to your output context (`" '<>` etc). For example, on Stack Overflow if they did not allow characters such as these you would be preventing questions and answers from including code snippets which would pretty much make the site useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not all SQL statements are parameterizable. For example, if you need to use dynamic identifiers (as opposed to literals). Even whitelisting can be hard, sometimes it needs to be dynamic.
2. Escaping XSS on output is a good idea. Until you forget to escape it on your admin dashboard too and they steal all your admin's cookies. Don't let XSS in your database.

Comment: 1. Still, the user input shouldn't be part of the actual SQL right?  So you can use SQL escaping.  I still see no need to disallow any characters.
2. I could say the same: "until you forget to validate the input in the legacy database migration script".  Besides, any decent web framework will by default use html escaping, and there's rarily a need to bypass it.